# Creating lists of Card objects

Tags: c#, winforms, static

I need to create two lists of Card objects in C#.

A `Card` class is defined as:

```
public class Card {
    public Suits Suit { set; get; }
    public Values Value { set; get; }
    public static Random rand = new Random();

    public Card() {

    }

    public Card(Suits s, Values v) {
        Suit = s;
        Value = v;
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return Suit.ToString() + " that has a value of " + Value.ToString();
    }

    public Card RandomCardGenerator() {
        Suit = (Suits)rand.Next(4);
        Value = (Values)rand.Next(1, 14);
        return this;
    }
```

In a different class called `Action`:

```
   static class Action {
        static public List< Card > CreateRandomCardList() {
            List< Card > cardList1 = new List< Card >();

            for (int loop = 0; loop < 12; loop++) {
                cardList1.Add(new Card().RandomCardGenerator());
            }

            return cardList1;
        }

        static public List < Card > CreateFullSetCard() {
            List< Card > cardList2 = new List< Card >();

            for (int s = 0; s < 4; s++) {
                for (int v = 0; v < 13; v++)
                    cardList2.Add(new Card((Suits)s, (Values)v));
            }

            return cardList2;
        }
    }
```

`CreateRandomCardList()` is later called upon:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
            PopulateListBox1(Action.CreateRandomCardList());
        }

        private void PopulateListBox1(List< Card > l) {
            listBox1.DataSource = l;
        }
}
```

I used `static` for class `Action`.

It makes sense to create instances of `Card`, but is it necessary to create an instance of `Action`? Can I keep it `static`?

Comment: We should see how those classes are used. For example: how do you test class which uses `Action`? To have a well-known input is important for its tests and static methods cannot be easily mocked. I'd rethink about the name: it's not descriptive and it also conflicts with System.Action (not a big issue if it was the "right" name)

Comment: @YuZhang - further to what Mr Adriano has said - it all depends on what you are using the classes for. Another issue is you gotta decide whether you want the card class to be simply a: (i) data structure, or (ii) an object (which hides its data behind abstractions). If it's a data structure, you could even let the suit classes be primitive types (e.g. strings) and expose them. one or the other is my recommendation. I'd leave it as a simple datastructure and put all methods pertaining to the card itself outside.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon, primitive types (or any simpler data structure) offers a better performance or it is simply about a better logic? (Since it is too simple to be an object?)

Comment: @YuZhang - because it's simpler. then again I haven't seen what the Suits class does. the basic point is this: decide whether you want to create an object or a data structure. in this case i think the latter might better suit your purposes because the Card class doesn't have any meaningful methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what `CreateRandomCardList` is intended for during gameplay. I know, technically, it's generating random cards but then why just 11 (`loop < 12`), why not 13?

Nevertheless, I strongly feel, the `Action` class is clearly misleading. I would instead prefer to have a `Deck` which knows what cards it holds. Also, `Card` type should be as simple as possible, perhaps knowing only `Suit` and `Value`. `RandomCardGenerator` does not belong there.

```
// Deck is general term. You can more appropriately
// name it as DeckOfCards, CardDeck, or anything you deem fit.
public class Deck {
    private Card[] cards;

    // Setup() is purposely part of Deck creation because without cards deck is useless.    
    public Deck() {
        // fill up 13 cards
        Setup();
    }

    private Cards[] Setup() {} // CreateFullSetCard()
    private Cards[] Shuffle() {}

    //.. so on
}
```

The `Deck` should not be static because

1. It is going to have it's own state.
2. If there are > 1 players, each will have their own Deck of cards. Even if it's single player, it should not be static for #1 reason.

Comment: I updated my question to include CreateRandomCardList. It is supposed to populate a listBox object on a windows form.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, Actions is fine as static.

Though, I agree with others that Action is an unclear name.

As has also been mentioned, RandomCardGenerator is a bit odd. At the very least, it should be a static method that returns a new Card. Better yet it could be moved to a different class (maybe Action).

You have a default constructor Card(), which means it is possible to create "blank" cards which you probably do not want.

Sometimes your sets of cards will contain multiple identical cards. A more "realistic" way to randomize cards is to create a full deck to form an array or collection of all 52 cards, then randomize numbers to pick cards from the deck.

Also note that a "regular" deck of cards have 4x13=52 cards, your full set method only generates 4x12, and your random set returns 11 cards.

Some people (including me) thinks even single line for/if/etc should have curly braces

ListBox1 should be renamed...

It seems in CreateFullSetCard you are creating 0-12, while in RandomCardGenerator you are using 1-13